Defaulting to gateway based integration instead of regional vnet integration in bicep issue
I'm trying to configure regional VNet integration for my Azure App Service using Bicep templates, but it defaults to gateway-based integration.
Here's the setup:
Network.Bicep:
@description('Name of the VNet to be created')
param vnetName string

@description('Name of the subnet to be created')
param subnetName string

@description('Name of the Network Security Group to be created')
param nsgName string

@description('Location for the resources')
param targetLocation string

@description('Desired set of tags to apply to each created resource')
param resourceTags object = {}

resource nsg 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-05-01' = {
  name: nsgName
  location: targetLocation
  properties: {
    securityRules: []
  }
  tags: resourceTags
}

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: targetLocation
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/27' // Adjusted to /27 for sufficient IPs
          serviceEndpoints: [
            {
              service: 'Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB'
            }
          ]
          delegations: [
            {
              name: 'webServerFarmDelegation'
              properties: {
                serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms'
              }
            }
          ]
          networkSecurityGroup: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', nsgName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  tags: resourceTags
}

output subnetId string = vnet.properties.subnets[0].id

Vnetintegration.bicep:
@description('The name of the existing web app to update')
param webAppName string

@description('Name of the existing web app Slot')
param webAppSlotName string?

@description('Denotes the desired name for the app service plan')
param appServicePlanName string

@description('The name of the virtual network')
param vnetName string

@description('The name of the subnet within the virtual network')
param subnetName string

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: webAppName
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' existing = {
  name: appServicePlanName
}

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-05-01' existing = {
  name: vnetName
}

resource vnetIntegration 'Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections@2021-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'vnet'
  properties: {
    vnetResourceId: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, subnetName)
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
    appServicePlan
  ]
}

Issue:
Despite specifying the VNet integration, the App Service defaults to gateway-based integration. How can I ensure that regional VNet integration is used instead?
